# How to set auto size the dynamic label box text in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tried follow code, My question passed to Label text, Question size longer than label text, So Can't view full question in label Box. Please solve this bug.

```
Label dynamiclabel = new Label();
dynamiclabel.Location = new Point(38, 30);
dynamiclabel.Size = new Size(200, 32);
dynamiclabel.Name = "lbl_ques";
dynamiclabel.Text = question;               
dynamiclabel.AutoSize = true;
dynamiclabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(900, 26);
dynamiclabel.Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/848139/Csharp-Correctly-Get-String-Width-in-Pixel

Comment: Link are not related to my Question.

Comment: Setting Size makes no sense when it has AutoSize=true. It __will__ grow horizontally as needed but if there is not enough space that won't help. To create multilines set AutoSize=false and make it higher..

Comment: But i have created Label box by dynamically. When i set label.AutoSize=false, the half of the questions displayed in label. Could you please write example Code?   @TaW41

Comment: Yes. Can you tell more about the layout? Posting an image of what is what should be is always very helpful. If you can't add it to the question you can upload it to some free fiel upload service.. - Are the Labels sitting inseide a parent? Is there enough space? Should they be multiline?

Comment: I have changed my answer to a simpler and more dynamic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

```
dynamiclabel.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(900, 26);
```

Explanation: The best way is to use a combination of `AutoSize = true` and a suitable `MaximumSize`: The layout in your form or container will set some limit of how wide the `Labels` are allowed to grow. If you don't control this they will grow to the right unlimited.. So setting that limit, taking into account space for scrollbar, padding, margins and some slack will give you the number to use in the MaximumSize property.

Let's add a couple of questions into a `FlowLayoutPanel` for easiest layout:

```
for (int q = 0; q < 50; q++) addQuestion(flowLayoutPanel1, q + 1);
```

Here is the routine that creates a question consisting of two labels:

```
void addQuestion(FlowLayoutPanel flp, int nr)
{
    Label l1 = new Label();
    l1.AutoSize = true;
    l1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Consolas", 9f, FontStyle.Bold);
    l1.Text = "Q" + nr.ToString("00") + ":";
    l1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 5, 10, 0);
    flp.Controls.Add(l1);

    Label l2 = new Label();
    l2.Text = randString(50 + R.Next(150));
    l2.Left = l1.Right + 5;
    l2.AutoSize = true;
    l2.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0, 5, 10, 0);
    // limit the size so that it fits into the flp; it takes a little extra
    l2.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(flp.ClientSize.Width - 
           l2.Left - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth  - l2.Margin.Right * 2, 0);
    flp.Controls.Add(l2);
    flp.SetFlowBreak(l2, true);
}
```

I use a tiny random string generator:

```
Random R = new Random(100);
string randString(int len)
{
    string s = "";
    while (s.Length < len) s+= (R.Next(5) == 0) ? " " : "X";
    return s.Length + " " + s + "?";
}
```

[image]

If you want to make the containersize dynamic just code the resize event to adapt the `MaximumSize` of the questions:

```
private void flowLayoutPanel1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    flowLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
    int maxWidth = flowLayoutPanel1.ClientSize.Width  - 
                   SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth ;
    foreach (Control ctl in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls )
    {
        if (ctl.MaximumSize.Width != 0)
           ctl.MaximumSize = new Size(maxWidth - ctl.Left - ctl.Margin.Right * 2, 0);
    }
    flowLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();
}
```

This will adapt the layout for all question labels..:

[image]